# Pivot viewer changing the default Filters

Tags: pivotviewer

I have created a simple Pivot viewer catelogue and in the Filter Panel it has a slider for the price with all other Facets below.
How do you bring one of them to the top and sort Alpha rather than Quantity?

Answer (score 0):

If you click the "Sort:Quantity" tag, it should change the sort to alpha.

Are you using the original PV or the new one in SL5?  To change the filters in the original one, you need to change the order of the facet definitions in the cxml file.  To change the filters in the SL5 version, you simply need to change the order of the PivotViewer properties.